# Generating a computer-specific UUID in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uuid, uniqueidentifier

How do I generate a UUID that will uniquely identify a computer using Xcode / Objective-C? Windows has `UuidCreateSequential()`, what can I use on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the system serial number or the hardware MAC addresses using IOKit.

Check out Apple Technical Note [TN1103](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn/tn1103.html) ("Uniquely Identifying a Macintosh Computer") for sample code and more information.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CFUUIDRef UUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
CFStringRef UUIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault,UUID);
// UUIDString is the CFStringRef (== NSString *) that contains the UUID.

// Cleanup
CFRelease(UUID);
CFRelease(UUIDString);
```

Comment: And is it Mac-specific, or will the Windows version (`UuidCreateSequential()`) give the same result?

Comment: According to this: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html, the UUID is unique across time and space. I need it to be the same across time because I want to be able to use it at any time to uniquely identify a computer. How do I do this?

Comment: You could use the MAC address. See GetPrimaryMACAddress sample code in XCode Developer Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
```

Comment: globallyUniqueString is guarantied to be unique across the network (according to the docs).  globallyUniqueString also doesn't guarantee the length or nature of the returned string, while UUID's have a prescribed format.